# Is there a way to run a test suite whenever some other test suite is run in a project?

Tags: java, testing, build.gradle, integration-testing, integration

To run a test class we can mention it in the Suite as a suite class using the @SuiteClasses({TestClass.class}).
If there are three packages with three different sets of integration tests I would have to manually include my test suite in all the three packages. I want to know if there is a way to automatically include my test class such that whenever any test suite runs in the project this particular class would load automatically?
I want to do this because in future if I add another integration test this class should automatically run even if I forget to mention it in @SuiteClasses({}).

I tried to run it by mentioning it in the @SuiteClasses({}); but I want to automate this. I am expecting it to run whenever an Integration test runs in that project.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Its simple that I want to run a test class whenever a test class is run in the project